# Running jshint via script produces NPM error: code ELIFECYCLE Exit status 2

Tags: javascript, jshint

Trying to run jsHint via script.
 
**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "projectName",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "jshint src"
  }
}
```

And get the following **error:**

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "lint"
npm ERR! node v4.2.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! projectName@0.1.0 lint: `jshint src`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this adding "|| true" to the lint line of the script in my package.json file. See below:

```
{
  "name": "projectName",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "jshint src || true"
  }
}
```

Comment: This solves this by suppressing the exit code altogether (If jshint has no findings it still works even without the || true). There is some good discussion in the comments here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6124